# Replace controlM character or a carriage return character and append the next line to previous line

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I am having a file like

```
"A","b","HI This is Bad","End of line1" -- This line1 is good
"A","C","THIS is^M      ------THis line2 is bad.
Good","End of line2"
```

I need the file to be like

```
"A","b","HI This is Bad","End of line1"
"A","C","THIS is Good","End of line2"
```

My file has a little more junk data after all. The data now looks like -

```
"A","b","HI This is Bad","End of line1" -- This line1 is good
"A","C","THIS is^M      ------THis line2 is bad.
Goo^M
d","End of line2"
```

So think like above might have multiple ^M rather than just 1 or 2. The solution given by Cyrus, works for only 1 ^M. What if I have n ^M, how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

sed '/\r$/{:a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g}' filename.csv>filename_final.csv

seems to have worked.

Basically created a label and looped it