# Can some one please explain sed '/\r$/{:a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g}' what its doing?

Tags: sed

Can some one please explain sed '/\r$/{:a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g}' what its doing?

sed '/\r$/{:a;N;$!ba;s/\r\n/ /g}' sourcefile>targetfile.csv

Comment: Have you looked at the sed [man page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/sed.html) or manual[http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) or the [sed Grymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)? Have you tried to make sense of it? Have you at least broken it down into its various pieces (split on `;`)? Generally you are expected to have made some attempt to solve your own problem before asking for help?

Comment: Déjà vu? http://stackoverflow.com/a/31621497/3776858